# Prevent HTML included in markdown file being processed further by Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

I'm working with Jekyll and want to use `{% include... %}` to include a snippet of HTML in a markdown file without that HTML being processed further, i.e. then being handled by the markdown processor as if it were just inline HMTL.

Note: I'm using *redcarpet* markdown (rather than e.g. kramdown).

Could this be handled with a Jekyll plugin?

I've created a GitHub repo [md-include-html](https://github.com/george-hawkins/md-include-html) with the following files that demonstrate my problem.

1. `_layouts/default.html` contains:

```
<div>
{{ content }}
</div>
```

2. `md-page.md` contains:

```
---
layout: default
---
A

{% include_relative html-snippet.html %}

B
```

3. `html-snippet.html` contains:

```
</div>
<!-- Some arbitrary HTML for {{ page.path }} -->
<div>
```

Note that I'm first attempting to close the div that will be introduced by `_layouts/default.html` and then open a new div at the end.

This results in `_site/md-page.html`:

```
<div>
<p>A</p>

<p></div>
&lt;!-- Some arbitrary HTML for md-page.md --&gt;
<div></p>
```

See how my comment has been processed and my content wrapped in `<p>...</p>`.

It seems the include happens before the markdown processing and there's no way to tell the markdown processor to handle the included text differently.

So I can include markdown in a HTML file with something like this (see [`html-page.html`](https://github.com/george-hawkins/md-include-html/blob/master/html-page.html) in my repo):

```
{% capture snippet_content %}
{% include_relative md-snippet.md %}
{% endcapture %}
{{ snippet_content | markdownify }}
```

But I can't include HTML in a markdown file.

I can't see a way around this without a markdown feature (anything done in Liquid essentially happens too early) to temporarily disable markdown processing.

E.g.

```
A

<markdown-off>{% include_relative html-snippet.html %}</markdown-off>

B
```

Yes I know the tags don't look very markdown-ish but you get what I mean.

Would there be some way to do this with a Jekyll plugin? I looked at those mentioned in the [plugin page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#available-plugins) of the Jekyll documentation but didn't spot anything immediately.

Comment: When I originally posted this question I hadn't specified `markdown: redcarpet` in the `_config.yml` file in the repo demonstrating this issue. I have now - as this is the markdown type I'm using in my real project.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this issue now. I am using includes to add snippets of html inside .md files in Jekyll. If you are using Kramdown you can add a markdown attribute inside your include snippet.

```
<div markdown="0"> !-- some html you don't want processed --> </div>
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

An old question I know, but have you tried wrapping it in the `{% raw %}` `{% endraw %}` ?

Try

```
</div>
{% raw}
<!-- Some arbitrary HTML for {{ page.path }} -->
{% endraw %}
<div>
```

This should stop the processing by the templating engine.

Indenting the comment by 4 spaces will mean that markdown will treat it as code, however Liquid will still process `{{ page.path }}`

Comment: Indenting by four spaces did the trick for me, thanks!